# Is there a way to retrieve a interval of dates as rows ms-sql?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to do a query to discover which days an employee didn't work.

For example:

If I retrieve all the dates between **21/07** and **25/07** that the employee worked I will have something like that:

```
21/07/2016
22/07/2016
23/07/2016
25/07/2016
```

But I want the days that he didn't work. In this case it's **24/07**.

I'm looking for a solution and my idea is to do a subquery retrieving an interval of dates, but as rows to do a **not contains** on the query above.

Example:

```
SELECT MyDate 
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyDate between 21-07 and 25-05
and MyDate not in 
**(the subquery here)**
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score -2):

Best way is with not exists and you need to query a table that has all the possible date values:

```
SELECT ALLDATECOLUMN FROM ALLDATES
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MYDATES WHERE MYDATES = ALLDATECOLUMN)
AND ALLDATECOLUMN BETWEEN 21-07 AND 25-05
```